# Disable auto scrolling in a TextArea

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols

In a TextArea:

```
TextArea
{
   id: outputText
   readOnly: true
   anchors.fill: parent
}
```

When I append text

```
outputText.append( "someText" )
```

The text area auto scrolls to the bottom.

Is there a way to turn off the auto scrolling?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to disable the scrolling, but the view will stay on top if you replace..

```
outputText.append(msg)
```

with..

```
outputText += msg
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the textArea codesource :

[https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtquickcontrols/source/73afeab85fea60e2ce3f19b47becffc1e45a7165:src/controls/TextArea.qml#L420-433](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtquickcontrols/source/73afeab85fea60e2ce3f19b47becffc1e45a7165%3asrc/controls/TextArea.qml#L420-433)

you'll see that the append function do :

```
function append (string) {
    edit.append(string)
    __verticalScrollBar.value = __verticalScrollBar.maximumValue
}
```

so if you always want the scroll bar to be up, you can add :

```
outputText.__verticalScrollBar.value = outputText.__verticalScrollBar.minimumValue
```

But if you want the scroll bar to stay exactly where it is when adding text, you should do :

```
outputText.text += (outputText.text ? "\n" : "") + "someText";
```